# Typescript errors after switching from npm to pnpm

Tags: typescript, npm, pnpm

I am trying to switch a legacy (very old fashioned Angular JS) project from npm to pnpm and am struggling with typescript errors.  The vast majority are things like
`error TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'.` Using npm I get a clean typescript transpile and I would like to keep it that way.

My tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding `import "angular";import "angular-mocks";` and `import "@types/angular";import "@types/angular-mocks";` but get`error TS2686: 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

I have also tried various hoisting options, but somewhat randomly as I don't have a great understanding of it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit:  To clarify, if I do

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json pnpm-lock.yaml npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm i --ignore-scripts
tsc
```

I get no errors (but it takes ages) whereas

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json pnpm-lock.yaml npm-shrinkwrap.json
pnpm i --ignore-scripts
tsc
```

relatively quickly yields 170 or so tsc errors, the vast majority of which are TS2339 errors.

Comment: delete `package-lock.json` and it'll stop work with npm too (try this, if it'll error I know answer)

Comment: Try https://pnpm.io/cli/import , will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was resolved by using preserveSymLinks
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveSymlinks